# Nginx: Correctly setting the mime type for gzipped styles/scripts

Tags: nginx

I have a gzip-compressed style and scripts in files:

```
/scripts.js.gz
/styles.css.gz
```

The problem is that it does not serve the correct mime-type and browser does not recognize, that the files are compressed css or js (browser recognize the type as application/octet-stream, where it should be text/css or so).

I tried adding the following to mime.type of nginx, but with no effect. I suppose, it does not recognize, that the file is compressed.

```
types {
    text/css                                css.gz;
    application/x-javascript                js.gz;
}
```

When trying to access the files, the browser handle the files as files to download and not to present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not change the mime types and use the [Gzip Static Module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_gzip_static_module.html) to handle this.

When this is active, Nginx will try to serve "file.ext.gz" first and then try "file.ext", if not found, for all requests within the context (location etc) where it is active.

Comment: This is not what I am looking for, I don't want to generate always two files (uncompressed and compressed), I have some cases, where I don't serve javascript, nor styles, but I want the mime type to be correctly send with the information that the file is gzipped.

Comment: Also, for instance, some files I serve by rewriting: /styles-frontend/ -> styles-frontend.css.gz – so I need it to send correctly the mimetype for given extension css.gz.

Comment: Your comments are not clear. Do you have files such as file.ext.gz that you want to serve? If yes, then the static module will serve them if they are present at the uri (whether rewritten or otherwise). However, you do not add the ".gz" to the request and just request ".ext".

Comment: I have a file in form of file.ext.gz and when I want to access it directly, even with the static module, it is not served correctly.

Comment: That is the point I was making. Just request file.ext and the gzip static module will take care of the rest. If there is a file.ext.gz present, Nginx will serve it. If not, it will serve file.ext. Leave the mime types alone.

Comment: This is still kind of "magic" solution: I really want to be in control of what is happening. For inst. I use directive "rewrite /styles-([0-9]+)\.css$ /data/styles.css last;" and once it is used, the headers are not send correctly again.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "magic" and not sure what more control you are seeking. This module was created to deal with your exact requirements. If you restore the mime types file to what it was originally and ***restart*** Nginx, "rewrite /styles-([0-9]+)\.css$ /data/styles.css last;" will serve /data/styles.css.gz with the "text/css" mime type. If it is not working for you, then you must have changed something in your setup. I suspect you may have changed the mime types file and not returned things back to the standard setup. You may need to clear your browser cache.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, coming from Apache.
The problem I found is, the `types` block does not allow you to specify `.css.gz` as a file extension. However, the `location` block does! My solution is to make a location for `.css.gz` and then modify the content type for `.gz` within that location, like this:

```
location ~ \.css\.gz$ {

   add_header  Content-Encoding  gzip;
   gzip off;
   types {
     text/css gz;
   }
}
```